# No power to some outlets after short circuit

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker

My room is connected to the room next to it so if I switch the breaker off my room and the room next to it all power turns off. I had an extension cord with wires that were exposed; they touched and sparked so when that happened all my outlets stopped working only in that room. My lights and fan still work and the power and outlets work in the other room. So what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you find which outlet still has power and which outlet the problem starts at?

Answer (score 1):

Odds are you burnt out the connection point to your one of your receptacles, or you blew apart a splice or pigtail. You need to find the downstream receptacle that is not working and the receptacle that is working just ahead of it. Generally you will find a loose or broken connection in one of those two places.

In short kill power, open the receptacles and try and determine how they are wired from the panel to the last outlet. Then check each receptacle and connection for something that is loose or disconnected. It will probably look burnt or damaged also. It's not a hard problem but does take some time.

Once you have found and fixed the problem reinstall your outlets the turn the power back on and verify everything is working.

Stay safe and good luck.

Comment: And (as I've learned over the last few months from numerous posts, but the OP might not know): If you find any receptacles with backstabs, change them to screw connections.

Comment: I agree usually it is the last working outlet or first nonworking outlet (terminology not as import and as location). If back stabs are used I would replace the outlet as this has been the failure point on hundreds of calls.

Comment: Yes, half the circuit dying after a heavy load is used, but the break happening at an unexpected place, *is the signature move of the backstab*... backstabs are also why AFCI is required everywhere now.